# Transistor with 2 LEDs

Tags: transistors

I have created the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6J0vg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a few questions regarding its function. I've seen that D1 stays constantly on while D2 flickers on and off during the cutoff and saturation region respectively.

When the transistor is functioning in the cutoff region (\$ V_{in} < V_{threshold} \$), it acts like an open switch and we have current flowing from \$ V_{CC} \$ through LEDs D1 and D2. I think my previous statement is correct.

I want some help on what happens when the transistor is functioning in the saturation region. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saturated, the voltage across the transistor (Vce) will be reduced to about 0.2V.  This effectively shorts the R3-D2 path so D2 stays off.  Also it increases the current through R2 and D1 because now the voltage from Vcc to the cathode of D1 is increased (to Vcc-0.2V).

Answer (score 1):

When transistor is off , then both LEDs will be on, BUT at reduced current since 2 R's are in series.

To toggle LED's a complementary BJT switch is preferred,  or a CMOS inverter  using 5V max.

For Fun I made the inverter an AC limiter with gain  so input must be terminated to some source and gnd to avoid antenna effects and stray noise detection.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Byvb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The cap can be replaced with an R ratio for gain if driving from a low level + signal or driven direct from logic level .